# How do I check irregular fields of request with express-validator

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

Due to a back-end plugin, my request is in form of

```
{ 
  fieldA: 123456,
  body: { something, somethingElse }
}
```

How do I check fieldA with express-validator?

Based on the doc(https://express-validator.github.io/docs/check-api.html), if I omit the field argument, it checks the body of request, and the only available fields are:

```
req.body
req.cookies
req.headers
req.params
req.query
```

Comment: Plz @Kazzit, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask
You should avoid asking for homework-like questions: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: Dunno why u think this is easy. Based on the doc of express-validator if i omit field it checks the body of request, and the only available fields are req.body,
req.cookies,req.headers,req.params,req.query.  How do i check req.fieldA? I tried several methods and none worked.P.S. It's back-end plugin in stead of front-end my bad for the typo.

Comment: I don't think is easy. I think this requires study to be asnwered, and that is exactly what you are not doing, and exactly what is requested for a good question too, a previous study.

Comment: Ok, got ur idea, editing the post.